# Is there a CheckStyle rule to force if else keywords to be on the same line in an if/else ladder?

Tags: java, regex, coding-style, checkstyle

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382633/can-the-checkstyle-module-needbraces-work-with-nested-ifelse-blocks) it appears that the default template for CheckStyle will allow if else ladders to separate the `if` and `else` with a line break.

Meaning I would like *this* code to be flagged as a violation:

```
if (true)
{
    System.out.println("20");   
}
else
    if (true)
    {
        System.out.println("30");
    }
```

Is there a CheckStyle rule to prevent this?  Looking over the docs, I don't see one, and I'd prefer not to use the generic regex rule, if I don't have to.

Also, if I use the *GenericIllegalRegexp* module, multiline regex don't seem to work.  Is there some remedy to this?

Comment: Just added correct Checkstyle module to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you can easily write a Checkstyle extension, since the AST browsing code of the [Checkstyle SDK Gui](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html) does not make any difference between:

```
else if
```

and

```
else
  if
```

In each case, `else` is a `LITERAL_ELSE` with in it an `if`...

So the generic regexp `else[ \t]*[\r\n]+[ \t]*if` is indeed a quick way to detect that kind of code.

---

Fix the regexp to include cases were :

- there is no space not tab before/after newline
- the is multiple newlines.

Of course, you do not want to use the `\s` whitespace regexp expression, since it includes itself newline characters. It is clearer to separate spaces from return characters.

---

Note: in Checkstyle 5.0beta, do not use "Generic Illegal Regexp", but rather the **"[Regexp" module](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#Regexp)**:
you can configure that RegExp module as 'illegalPattern' (with an associated Severity of 'Warning'), and you do not have to use any kind af 'multi-line' flag: the regexp is enough.

> **Regexp**
> Description
>
> A check that makes sure that a specified pattern exists, exists less than a set number of times, or does not exist in the file.
>
> This check combines all the functionality provided by RegexpHeader, GenericIllegalRegexp and RequiredRegexp, except supplying the regular expression from a file.
>
> **It differs from them in that it works in multiline mode**. It's regular expression can span multiple lines and it checks this against the whole file at once. The others work in singleline mode. Their single or multiple regular expressions can only span one line. They check each of these against each line in the file in turn.

---

[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005481/thomas) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387008/is-there-a-checkstyle-rule-to-force-if-else-keywords-to-be-on-the-same-line-in-a/387528?noredirect=1#comment31182446_387528):

> The checkstyle AST does have line number information.

See "[Is there any Checkstyle/PMD/Findbugs rule to force “`else if`” to be on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20799612/6309)"
(in which one has to use a [custom check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html), and not a [regex match](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#Regexp)).

Comment: Course if you use + instead of * as the quantifier, it will ignore poorly formed code which doesn't have extra spaces on both lines.

Comment: Update.  This doesn't seem to work, as checkstyle appears to ignore regular expressions that rely on the MULTILINE flag, even if you use the embedded flag in your expression.

Comment: I do confirm the regexp is correctly detected in multi-line configuration in Checkstyle: it does not require any (?m) multiline flag to work

Comment: Could this be an issue with CheckStyle version? (I'm on the 5.0beta)  Using the regex you provided doesn't flag the code in my example.  (BTW, I agree wiht your version of the regex, if only it worked. It looks like it should, but I get no style error)

Comment: Also, I'll add that I can change the regex used to a single line match and it works, so I'm strongly convinced that there is something working funny related to multiline matches.

Comment: You are right: Do not use Generic Illegal Regexp, but rather "Regexp". See my answer I just completed

Comment: That does it.  Thank you much for all the help.  Looks to me like CheckStyle questions don't get much traffic...

Comment: FYI, the checkstyle AST *does* have line number information. See [similar answer to a different question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20799612/1005481).

Comment: @Thomas good to know: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @Thomas Ok, I have edited the answer and mention the need for a custom check.