# Is there any Checkstyle/PMD/Findbugs rule to force "else if" to be on the same line?

Tags: java, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

In our project for chained if/else/if we would like to have following formatting:

```
if (flag1) {
    // Do something 1
} else if (flag2) {
    // Do something 2
} else if (flag3) {
    // Do something 3
}
```

And forbid following one:

```
if (flag1) {
    // Do something 1
} else {
    if (flag2) {
        // Do something 2
    } else {
        if (flag3) {
            // Do something 3
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some predefined rule in either of listed above static code analysis tools to force this code style? If no - I know there is an ability to write custom rules in all of those tools, which one would you suggest to implement such a rule (not really familiar with writing custom rules in either of them)?

Comment: I recommend solving this by using your IDE's automatic code formatter.

Comment: I want my continuous integration build to be failed as soon as someone violated this rule. I can't achieve this by using IDE's formatting rules.

Comment: There is no FindBugs rule, because FindBugs analyses byte code not source code.

Comment: Well, Checkstyle also analyses byte code...

Comment: Checkstyle and PMD only use source code. FindBugs only uses byte code.

Comment: Hm, you're right. I was probably confused by some old version of maven checkstyle plugin, which forced me to recompile sources in order to make changes visible for checkstyle. Just retested it with our current version of maven checkstyle plugin and it works without recompilation. Or maybe I was confused by something else... Somehow I was sure it uses bytecode. Anyway thanks. Now I know the truth :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with CheckStyle, but you'll have to [code a custom check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html).

Using a custom check allows you to completely ignore comments. The line number that a token is on can be determined by calling [`getLineNo()`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/DetailAST.html#getLineNo%28%29) on the DetailAST. Here's what the AST looks like, with line number information (red circles):

[image]

The custom check's code will likely be quite short. You basically register for `LITERAL_ELSE` tokens and see if `LITERAL_IF` is their only child. Also remember to handle `SLIST`s. In those cases, `LITERAL_IF` and `RCURLY` should be the only children. Both cases are illustrated in the above picture.

---

#### Alternative using a RegExp check

For the record, I originally thought one could also configure a [regex match](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#Regexp) using `else[ \t{]*[\r\n]+[ \t{]*if\b` for the `format` property (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/387528/1005481)).

Here's the mentioned regex as a railroad diagram:
[image: regex visualization]

This turned out not to be feasible, because it produces false negatives when there are comments between between `else` and `if`. Worse, it also produces false positives when the nested `if` is followed by unrelated code (like `else { if() {...} <block of code>}`. Thanks @Anatoliy for pointing this out! Since comments and matching braces which are mixed with comments cannot be reliably grasped by regexes, these problems obsolete the RegExp approach.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was thinking about regexp. Problem with it is that it will be false positive on cases, when we have some block of code after or before "if" (like: "else { if {...} <block of code>}"). The same issue is actually with XPath for PMD. So I'll have to implement custom check. This isn't an issue, I'll figure out how to do this. I just wanted to clarify if there are some predefined ones...

Comment: Dang, you are right. I updated my answer accordingly. You'll have to write a check. I added some links and info on how to go about that.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387008/is-there-a-checkstyle-rule-to-force-if-else-keywords-to-be-on-the-same-line-in-a) says you can't do it in Checkstyle.

In PMD you definitely can.  The AST (abstract syntax tree) is different.

**For the pattern you don't want**

```
if (true) {
  String a;
} else {
  if (true) {
    String b;
  }
}
```

The tree looks like:

```
<IfStatement>
  <Expression>...</Expression>
  <Statement>...</Statement>
  <Statement>
    <Block>
      <BlockStatement>
        <IfStatement>...
```

**For the pattern you do want**

```
if (true) {
  String a;
} else if (true) {
  String b;
}
```

The tree looks like:

```
<IfStatement>
  <Expression>...</Expression>
  <Statement>...</Statement>
  <Statement>
    <IfStatement>...
```

In PMD 4 (which I used to make these trees), you write a rule by writing a XPath expression matching the pattern you don't want to occur.

Comment: Hi Jeanne. I saw post mentioned by you, thanks. But actually it says that line break between "else" and "if" is not distinguishable by checkstyle. I have another case, it's exactly one nested "if" block (withing curly braces) right after an "else" block. So case is different and I think must be perfectly distinguishable by checkstyle (I know it has a lot of rules to check if curly braces are in place or not).

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your suggestion regarding PMD. Will look at it.